# Prime Number Check Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I mede the prime number generator in JavaScript:

```
function prime(from, to) {
        for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            var IsPrime = false;
            for (var j = from; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    IsPrime = true;
                }
            }
            if (IsPrime == false) {
                console.log([i]);
            }
        }
    }

    prime(2, 9999);
```

But the output looks like this...

```
[2]
[3]
[5]
[7]
[11]
...
```

...and I want it to look like this:

```
[2,3,5,7,11...]
```

can someone help me?
thanks for your ideas;-)

Comment: You might be interested in learning about [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), so that you can get the numbers as they come up rather than calculate them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function prime(from, to) {
    var result = []; // creating a variable for accumulating
    for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        var IsPrime = false;
        for (var j = from; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                IsPrime = true;
            }
        }
        if (IsPrime == false) {
            // console.log([i]);
            result.push(i); // adding value
        }
    }
    console.log(result) // console.log result
    return result // returning for further usage
}

var a = prime(2, 9999); // put result into a variable
console.log(a); // console.log again for example
```

Answer (score 1):

You're logging inside your loop. instead, push the results into an array, and just log the array at the end

```
function prime(from, to) {
        var primearray = [];
        for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            var IsPrime = false;
            for (var j = from; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    IsPrime = true;
                }
            }
            if (IsPrime == false) {
                primearray.push(i);
            }
        }
    console.log(primearray)
    }

    prime(2, 9999);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are logging each element separately. If you would like to have the output as an array - you can create an empty array and `.push()` elements to it.

See the example below.

```
function prime(from, to) {
        let primeArray = [];
        for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            var IsPrime = false;
            for (var j = from; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    IsPrime = true;
                }
            }
            if (IsPrime == false) {
                primeArray.push([i]);
            }
        }
     console.log(primeArray)
    }

    prime(2, 9999);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
function prime(from, to) {
        let output = []
        for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            var IsPrime = false;
            for (var j = from; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    IsPrime = true;
                }
            }
            if (IsPrime == false) {
               output.push([i]);
            }
        }
    print(output)
    }

    prime(2, 9999);
```

Comment: `output` is out os scope while you are printing the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add numbers to array:

```js
function prime(from, to) {
  var arr = [];
  
  for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    var IsPrime = false;
    for (var j = from; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            IsPrime = true;
        }
    }
    if (IsPrime == false) {
        arr.push(i);
    }

    if(i === to) {
      return arr;
    }            
  }
}

console.log(prime(2, 10));
```